# Show that if $X(\omega) = \infty$ then $EX = \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to show that if $X(\omega) = \infty \space\forall \omega \in A$, $P(A) > 0$ and $X \ge 0$ then  $EX = \infty$.

The problem comes with a hint:

$$EX = E\{X[I(A) + I(A^c)]\} = E[XI(A)] + E[XI(A^c)] \ge E[XI(A)] \ge E[MI(A)]$$
for all constants $M \ge 0$.

At this point I just show that:

$$EX \ge ME[I(A)] $$

Since $E[I(A)]$ is just a constant, call it $c$,

$$EX \ge Mc $$

Set $N = Mc$ and then

$$EX \ge N$$

for any constant $N$, and so $EX = \infty$.

Is this correct? I think I might've missed something since technically it's greater than or equal to, not just greater. Also, I'm not sure why the restrictions that $X \ge 0$ and $M \ge 0$ are necessary.

Comment: To assume that X is nonnegative everywhere is necessary to ensure that EX exists (not as a real but in the extended positive real halfline [0,+oo]).

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked your calculations but the result achieved is sufficient. If your number is greater than or equal to any positive integer it must be infinite because the positive integers are infinite.

As to the restriction, what happens is $EX\ge-N$? $EX=0$ is a solution and it isn't infinite!

Comment: But if M ranges across the reals, that the restriction irrelevant since the expectation has to be bigger than all the reals, so it has to be bigger than $N$ as well as $-N$?